# Unable to locate WordPress Content directory (wp-content)

Tags: errors, updates

I have tried to update my plugins in wordpress-admin but for some reason i am receiving an error "Unable to locate WordPress Content directory (wp-content)" I have checked on my server and the folder still exists. What is this cause of this and is there a quick fix?

Comment: Try defining the constant in wp-config.php - WP_CONTENT_DIR - https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories

Comment: I recently got the same error I wonder if it was because I upgraded to PHP 7.0

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, this is usually a permission of writing in specific folder, in my case I had to change the owner of the `uploads/` directory, here is what I did in `wp-content` directory:

```
sudo chown -R daemon uploads/
```

where the user `daemon` is the owner of the process `httpd`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Adding below code to `wp-config.php` file will solve your problem:

```
if(is_admin()) {
   add_filter('filesystem_method', create_function('$a', 'return "direct";' ));
   define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', 0751 );
}
```

Above is quick fix I found on Wordpress support but problem is with permissions.

[For details please follow link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-locate-wordpress-content-directory-wp-content?replies=15)

Please check you permissions:

All FILES should have permissions set to 644

All DIRECTORIES (i.e. folders) should have permissions set to 755

[For Correct file Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress)

Thanks!

Comment: Added to functions now it says "The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions. "

Comment: Please try to check permission of your folders, according to updated answer.

Comment: Please follow this link to check with permissions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Also had this error and it was because of server FTP and NAT configuration and I was updating WordPress via FTP. Changing the WP update page to use the IP address of the web server instead of the domain name of the web site solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS to host your site, open the file explorer on the server and right click on your website (WordPress) folder. Select Properties --> Security and edit the "USERS" permissions to enable Read, Write, List, and Modify privileges.

Doing this also fixed my issue with importing content data.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution at the following link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ymc1CBdbsJ8

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/258017)

Comment: As already pointed out, link-only answers can become invalid later. Might I suggest that you give expanding your answer a go? Edit your answer to include a brief summary so that your answer can become a valuable resource in its own right.